# Set a limit for forms with the same value Django

Tags: django, forms, limit

So what I want to do is to set a limit of forms with the same value. There are different activities from a foreign model to which students can apply.
I have name(naam), student number(studentnummer), activity(activiteit) and class(klas), and I want to set a limit of 10 forms with the same activity (max of people who can do the same activity) and a limit of 1 for student number (so students can only apply for one activity).

**models.py**

```
class Klas(models.Model):
    klas = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.klas}"
    
class Activiteit(models.Model):
    titel = CharField(max_length=64)
    docent = CharField(max_length=32)
    icon = models.ImageField()
    uitleg = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}:{self.titel}:{self.docent}"
    
class Aanmelden(models.Model):
    naam = CharField(max_length=32)
    studentnummer = IntegerField()
    klas = ForeignKey(Klas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    activiteit = ForeignKey(Activiteit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}:{self.naam}:{self.studentnummer}"
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
   activiteiten = Activiteit.objects.all()
   
   form = AanmeldenForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AanmeldenForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           
   return render(request, 'home.html', {
       'activiteiten': activiteiten,
       'form':form,
   })
```

**forms.py**

```
class AanmeldenForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Aanmelden
       fields = (
           'naam','studentnummer','klas','activiteit'
       )
```

**If you know how to solve this or have a better idea of doing this kind of system please let me know.
Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have a variable inside your `Aktiviteit` class, such as `plaatsen_beschikbaar` that is initialised at 10 when you create a new instance of an `Aktiviteit`. Then on successful `Aanmelden` to an instance you reduce it by one. You need to make sure in your model that `plaatsen_beschikbaar` cannot be less than zero, and if someone deletes the aanmelding then increase the variable by 1. Edit: or you use a validator such as the one below to restrict Aanmelden. You could also make your model have a @property that returns the `plaatsen_beschikbaar` instead of using a field. On second thought, this seems like a better plan, hence this edit

To make sure a student may only have 1 `Aanmelden`, you could just make your `studentnummer` unique in your `Aanmelden` class. But that makes your model not future-proof if you decide in future that students may subscribe to two or three activities. In that case you need to have a foreign key relationship to `Student` and restrict the number of `Aanmelden` that a student may have using a validator like so for instance

```
def beperk_aanmelden(value):
    if Aanmelden.objects.filter(student_id=value).count() >= 1:
        raise ValidationError('Student heeft al de maximale aanmeldingen')
    else:
        return value
```

Then in your `Aanmelden` model:

```
student = ForeignKey(Student, validators=[beperk_aanmelden,])
```

Edit: based on your current model it would look like this:

```
def beperk_aanmelden(value):
    if Aanmelden.objects.filter(studentnummer=value).count() >= 1:
        raise ValidationError('Student heeft al de maximale aanmeldingen')
    else:
        return value
```

And in your model:

```
studentnummer = IntegerField(validators=[beperk_aanmelden,])
```

Edit 2:

To check the `plaatsen_beschikbaar` you could do something like this:

```
def beperk_activiteit(value):
    if Activiteit.objects.get(activiteit_id=value).plaatsen_beschikbaar <= 0:
        raise ValidationError('Activiteit heeft geen plaatsen beschikbaar meer! Kies een andere activiteit.')
```

Then for the field in your model:

```
activiteit = ForeignKey(Activiteit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, validators=[beperk_activiteit,])
```

Edit 3:

For the `plaatsen_beschikbaar` I would do something like this. Each `Activiteit` has a `capaciteit` where you set the maximum places available. Then define an `@property`, which gives you a non-db calculated field which you can access just like a normal field. The difference is that it's not stored, but re-calculated each time you access it. Inside count the number of `Aanmelden` that have the `Activiteit` instance as related object. That's your number of already booked placed. Then subtract this from `capaciteit` and you'll have a current `plaatsen_beschikbaar`

```
class Activiteit(models.Model):
    titel = CharField(max_length=64)
    docent = CharField(max_length=32)
    icon = models.ImageField()
    uitleg = models.TextField()
    capaciteit = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def plaatsen_beschikbaar(self):
        geboekt = Aanmelden.objects.filter(activiteit_id=self.id).count()
        return self.capaciteit - geboekt

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}:{self.titel}:{self.docent}"
```

Comment: Hey, The first one works perfect but I'm having some trouble to apply the second one because I don't have a class for student. How could I create a student class and still including it in the same form as Aanmelden? the idea is that people enter to the website anonymously, fill a form and get into the group of an activity.

Comment: @enmanuel-v I The validator should also work for an integer `studentnummer=value` in the validator and then in the model `studentnummer = Integerfield(validators=[beperk_aanmelden,])`

Comment: I've tried that but there's no model called Student so there's no student_id for `Aanmelden.objects.filter(student_id=value).count()`

Comment: @Enmanuel-V updated my answer

Comment: @Enmanuel-V Sorry, I just realised I forgot to add the `return` in the validator function in my original answer. Apologies! I just corrected.

Comment: Now it works perfect! thanks. I tried to do something similar for the activities but it doesn't work and I don't know how to do it. I have this     `if Aanmelden.objects.filter(studentnummer=value).count() >= Activiteit.objects.filter(plaatsen_beschikbaar=value).get:`

Comment: @Enmanuel-V `Aanmelden.objects.filter(studentnummer=value)` returns a queryset with all Aanmelden objects that have `value` for `studentnummer` So when you take the `count()` of that queryset, it gives you a way to limit the number of `Aanmelden` for a given `studentnummer` value. `Activiteit.objects.filter(plaatsen_beschikbaar=value)` would give you a queryset of all `Activiteiten` with `value` plaatsen beschikbaar. That's a different `value`! And comparing makes no sense. What do you want to validate exactly?

Comment: I want to set the `plaatsen_beschikbaar` value from `Activiteit` as a limit for how many students an activity can have. So I thought I could use the same function but making the limit dynamic with the other model, because every activity has a different limit of students.

Comment: For completeness sake I need to add that instead of using a custom validator, you can also use your model's clean() method and do all your validation inside that. Alternatively, each field also has its own clean_field() method that you can use. So clean_studentnummer() in your case for instance. # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean
    def clean(self):

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to make the discounter of plaatsen_beschikbaar? I've been trying but I can't make it work. If I have that then the validator for activities will work, otherwise It'll never reach 0. Thanks in advance

Comment: Updated my answer. This is probably the easiest way to give you a real-time number of available places. Just count the number of booked places and subtract from a capacity field.

Comment: Hi, I can still adding more aanmelden than the capaciteit I've set for a model :(

Comment: Then you'll have to do some debugging. Unfortunately, I'm in bed with covid and I'm responding to you from memory on a mobile phone, lol. Check if `plaatsen_beschikbaar` returns the correct value. Perhaps the validator doesn't quite work? Instead of validating the field with a validator you can also easily do this inside the `clean(self)` method of your `Aanmelden` model, which is easier to understand. Look at the docs I linked above. Inside `clean(self)` you check if there are enough plaatsen_beschikbaar and raise Validation Error if there aren't.